# Ionic black screen on mobile web

Tags: ios, angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework, mobile-website

I'm using Ionic strictly for a mobile web site (no native builds).  Local development in my browser appears to be working just fine.  However when I try to load the site on my iphone I get nothing but a black screen.  Using safari web inspector I opened up the console and don't see any errors.  Has anyone experienced this issue?  I would post code, but at the moment I have no idea what to post because I'm not sure where to begin with this issue.

Comment: This can happen from not using the right combination of directives and states, can you post your state declarations and the main markup?